# Stopping Handler runnable tasks when destroying activity

Tags: android, concurrency, synchronization, dispose

I usually delegate all Activities events to a separate controller class, which has a special method for handling events from `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(int what, Object data) {
    switch (what) {
    case ExerciseViewEvent.STARTUP:
        workerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                onStartup();
            }
        });
        return true;
}
```

This is done in order to keep UI thread responsive and make all computations in background tasks.

However, when `Activity.onDestroy()` method is called by the system, `controller.dispose()` method is called, which cleans up all stuff in controller this way

```
@Override
protected synchronized void dispose() {
    .................
    if (model != null) {
        synchronized (model) {
            model.dispose();
        }
        model = null;
    }
    helper = null;
    .....................
    super.dispose();
}
```

As you can see, disposing of controller happens in UI thread, without delegating it to a handler thread.

The problem happens when, for example, `onDestroy` is called in the middle of `onStartup()` method: `onDestroy` cleans up the model and all other references, but inside `onStartup` method it tries to access the model at some point, but considering it is `null`, an exception is thrown.

What is the best way for resolving this issue? I do not want to lock every controller method because some of them may happen simultaneously without interfering each other.

Comment: Moreover, it is possible that onDestroy method is not called by the system.

Comment: Good point Yuri, but if it's not called, then all objects allocated by the activity are destroyed by JVM themself? So I do not have to worry about it, right? In dispose I have only disposing of all objects, nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the dispose() method you should cleanup the workerHandler before disposing of the model.  See the [`removeCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [removeCallbacksAndMessage(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29) methods in the Handler class.  The latter method removes all callbacks and messages when the argument is `null`.

Comment: workerHandler is type of Handler. How can I cancel all runnables that were added to this Handler using post() method?

Comment: yes, but this means that I need to track all callbacks I add, otherwise I do not know what callbacks should I remove. There's no mehtod like "removeAllCallbacks()" or something. I should then have a list like `List<Runnable>` and store all runnables there.